# What is the difference between imregionalmax() of matlab and scipy.ndimage.filters.maximum_filter

Tags: python, matlab, image-processing, computer-vision, image-segmentation

I need to find the regional maxima of an image to obtain foreground markers for watershed segmentation. I see in matlab use the function [`imregionalmax()`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imregionalmax.html). As I don't have the matlab software, I use the function [`scipy.ndimage.filters.maximum_filter()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.filters.maximum_filter.html) instead. However, the results from `imregionalmax()` and `scipy.ndimage.filters.maximum_filter()` are different.

Please help me how to find out the regional maxima of an image. Thanks very much for your help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It appears as if scipy's `maximum_filter` returns the actual local max values, while Matlab's `imregionalmax` returns a mask with the *locations* of the local maxima.
I would expect

```
 lm = scipy.ndimage.filters.maximum_filter( img, ... )
 msk = (img == lm) #// convert local max values to binary mask
```

should give you similar results to Matlab's.

Comment: I got similar results to Matlab's. Thanks so much.

Comment: you know it's true but `scipy.ndimage.filters.masximum_filter(...)` isn't like `imregionalmax ` how ever it makes the index boolean but it's not the same

Answer (score 4):

I am new to Python but I spent a lot of time to find the 100% equivalent of Matlab's `imregionalmax()`. For me, the above,  `msk = (img == lm)` did NOT work because of my huge 3D arrays. I instead used `scikit-images.peak_local_max` as follows:

1) define `conn_26` to be 3x3x3 array of one's.

2) `coordinates = peak_local_max(3D_img, footprint=conn_26,indices=False,exclude_border=0)`

is similar to `coordinates = imregionalmax(3D_img,26)`

Hope this helps :)